# Two questions asked. One answered by two people before it was removed

Tags: discussion

[random unscheduled jogging?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32005/random-unscheduled-jogging)

The querent asked about how effective unscheduled jogging was and also about nausea they were experiencing. Two of the three answers are about the nausea and only the nausea. Then JohnP removed that bit to turn it into a single question. How exactly do we handle this? Based on the title, the primary concern was how effective the random running was. But there are more answers for the removed bit.

So, should the answers to the (now removed) part of the question be flagged for deletion? Should the question be reverted so that the edit doesn't make the answers nonsensical? Ideally, the querent would post his second question if he felt it was still relevant to him and then encourage the two people with answers to resubmit them to the new question, but we're currently left with the immediate issue of a single question which is answered by one of the three answers and two answers that are addressing the question that the editor felt was unimportant.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking: _How exactly do we handle this_?  Please be more specific as to your concern(s).

Comment: Sorry. I have clarified my position that the edit left the majority of the answers seeming nonsensical.

Comment: I did remove the second bit. It wasn't answerable, as the answers all show (See a doctor, see a doctor, and one wrong answer). I will admit it makes the answers a bit funky, ideally the original answerers would edit to reflect the change. I could roll it back, but it would me *more* likely to be closed as seeking medical advice.

Comment: {nods} So should the other answers get flagged and/or removed?